# How to apply two styles in one column

Tags: html, css

If i have a TD(table column) . Like

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>* Name</td>
        <td><input type="text"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Is it possible that i apply two styles in the first column. Like i want that my asterisk seems red and name seems blue. If i take it in two columns then it is possible, like

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td style color="red">*</td>
        <td style color="blue">Name</td>
        <td><input type="text"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

But i want to know is it possible in the first case when both * and Name text are in the same column?

Thanks

Comment: can you wrap the asterisk in a span? like `<td style='color: blue;'><span style='color: red;'>*</span>Name</td>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I would use `<span style="color: red">` around the asterisk inside the td and you can either style the whole td w/ the blue or just the name if you plan on having uncolored areas inside the td.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td style="color: blue;"><span style="color: red;">*</span> Name</td>
        <td><input type="text"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This is the right idea, but I would do this with a class instead. `<span class="accent">*</span>` where the css has `.accent { color: red }`. There's a time and a place to be pedantic, but I think this is a good candidate for a class. You may have other text (not just asterisks) that should get the accent color. Of course, the name "accent" should be changed to something that makes semantic sense to you (just not "red" since the colour may change some day).

Comment: Completely agree with Greg, just tried to keep the code super simple so Basit could understand in as simple terms as possible!

Comment: Simplicity often more important than "best practices" when it comes to providing guidance and instruction, that's for sure.

Comment: I used this `<span style="color: red;">*</span><span style="color:blue;"> #{label.newsHeadline}</span>` in td and it is working. Greg Petti commnents add clarity to the answer. Thanks to you both:)

Answer (score -2):

You can use 2 css classes like:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="Red Blue">Name</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

css:

```
.Red {
background-color: red;
}

.Blue {
background-color: blue;
}
```

But I don't know situations when we need it.

Comment: @Evl-ntnl Where is asterisk gone?  Did you mean this `<td class="Red Blue">* Name</td>`

Comment: I think you read the title of the question and jumped into an answer without reading the full requirement.